# How can I use a Typescript array in my HTML when using primeng chips?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, primeng

As mentioned in my subject line how can I change this:

**HTML**

```
<p-chip label="1 day(s)" styleClass="p-mb-2 p-mr-2 custom-chip"></p-chip>
<p-chip label="2 day(s)" styleClass="p-mb-2 p-mr-2 custom-chip"></p-chip>
<p-chip label="3 day(s)" styleClass="p-mb-2 p-mr-2 custom-chip"></p-chip>
...
```

To something like this:

**TS**

```
days: string[] = [
'1 day(s)', '2 day(s)', '3 day(s)', '4 day(s)',
'5 day(s)', '6 day(s)', '7 day(s)'
```

];

**HTML**

```
<p-chips label="day of days" style="p-mb-2 p-mr-2 custom-chip"></p-chips>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<p-chips *ngFor="let day of days" [label]="day" class="p-mb-2 p-mr-2 custom-chip"></p-chips>
```

Comment: thanks very much, there were a few changes I needed to make to your solution above, but you pointed me in the right direction!